# Can use ASPNet.Identity in Non-Web application

Tags: c#, console-application, asp.net-identity, class-library

I have used aspnet membership earlier. Now I am planning to migrate the code to aspnet.Identity 2. And there is one section of my project where sometimes I need to create an user programmatically from a class library.

How can I do this using Identity in a class library or Console app for testing?

Comment: How do you mean? You could import the identity namespaces into your project. Or are you trying to stay away from that?

Comment: @Shoe Even if I import identity namespace, how do I use that? I bit confused over there. According to MSDN article they prefer the configuration to be initialized by Startup. And I am not able to refer to UserManager. how can I do that? can you please provide an example?

Comment: You could just get the user from the DB directly. Otherwise you could instantiate a Usermanager.